# AnyTrue is too good (compared to MemberQ)

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, built-in-symbols

Let L be a list of integers, and ⓝ denote an explicit integer.

I've thought the most natural way to tell whether ⓝ belongs to L is

```
In[1]  MemberQ[L, ⓝ]
```

But there are problems.

1>> If `Length[L]` is too big(around 10^9), then the code is indeed harmful. Mathematica automatically quits krenel(lose every definition).

2>> Try

```
 In[2]  MemberQ[Range[10^8],1]//Timing
 Out[2]  (* Takes about 3 seconds, too long *)
```

If we know ⓝ appears very early in L, then using MemberQ may be inefficient.

Now `AnyTrue` technique is the following :

```
 In[3]  AnyTrue[L, #==ⓝ&]
```

Introducing advantages :

1. The code works well even in case `Length[L]` is too big.
2. If ⓝ appears very early in L, then it takes very short time.
   (more precisely, the earlier, the shorter)
3. Its usage is much more diverse than `MemberQ.`

**So I'll never use MemberQ if** `Length[L]` is too big **or if** I know ⓝ appears early in L.

But I found an advantages of MemberQ, it behaved faster for irregular data.

```
L=RandomSample[Range[10^8]];
 MemberQ[L, ⓝ]//Timing
 AnyTrue[L, #==ⓝ&]//Timing
```

There can be other better method. Can you tell me more about these kind of things ?
I mean performance of various test(that can tell the existence of something in the list).

Comment: Is this a one-time MemberQ of a list, or would you be doing multiple MemberQ of the same list?

Comment: What is causing the first two problems? And, is `MemberQ` really not shortcutting?

Comment: `IntersectingQ[L,{n}]//Timing`

Comment: AnyTrue is faster than MemberQ in many situations but techniques mentioned in the comments and answers behaves even faster!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One possibility for lists of integers is to use [`Clip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clip):

```
iMemberQ[l_, s_] := s == Max @ Clip[l, {s, s}, {s-1, s-1}]
```

For your examples:

```
L = Range[10^8];
iMemberQ[L, 1] //AbsoluteTiming
iMemberQ[L, 10^8] //AbsoluteTiming
iMemberQ[L, 10^9] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.729907, True}

> {0.648677, True}

> {0.631598, False}

```
L = RandomSample[Range[10^8]];
iMemberQ[L, 1] //AbsoluteTiming
iMemberQ[L, 10^8] //AbsoluteTiming
iMemberQ[L, 10^9] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.651394, True}

> {0.616799, True}

> {0.613475, False}

If you need to do membership tests for multiple elements with the same list, you could consider using [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) ([`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest)  is a little slow, but only needs to be done once):

```
SeedRandom[1];
L = RandomSample @ Range[10^8];

nf = Nearest[Sort @ L]; //AbsoluteTiming
nMemberQ[nf_, s_] := Length[nf[s, {1, 0}]] > 0

nMemberQ[nf, 1] //AbsoluteTiming
nMemberQ[nf, 10^8] //AbsoluteTiming
nMemberQ[nf, -1] //AbsoluteTiming
```

> {21.915, Null}

> {0.000957, True}

> {0.000041, True}

> {0.000995, False}

Answer (score 6):

```
list1 = Range[10^8];
list2 = RandomInteger[10^10, 10^8];
list3 = RandomInteger[10, 10^8];

elem = 5;


MemberQ[list1, elem] // AbsoluteTiming
MemberQ[list2, elem] // AbsoluteTiming
MemberQ[list3, elem] // AbsoluteTiming

memberQCompiled = Compile[{{a, _Integer, 1}, {e, _Integer}}, MemberQ[a, e]];
memberQCompiled[list1, elem] // AbsoluteTiming
memberQCompiled[list2, elem] // AbsoluteTiming
memberQCompiled[list3, elem] // AbsoluteTiming


Random`Private`PositionsOf[list1, elem] =!= {} // AbsoluteTiming
Random`Private`PositionsOf[list2, elem] =!= {} // AbsoluteTiming
Random`Private`PositionsOf[list3, elem] =!= {} // AbsoluteTiming

(* Using librarylink, need a C++ compiler *)
isMember[list1, elem] // AbsoluteTiming
isMember[list2, elem] // AbsoluteTiming
isMember[list3, elem] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"];
$CCompiler={"Compiler"->CCompilerDriver`GenericCCompiler`GenericCCompiler,"CompilerInstallation"->"C:/msys64/mingw64","CompilerName"->"g++.exe","CompileOptions"->"-O2"};

src="#include \"WolframLibrary.h\"
#include <algorithm>

EXTERN_C DLLEXPORT bool is_member(WolframLibraryData libData, mint Argc, MArgument *Args, MArgument Res) {
    mint *in_data;
    MTensor in = MArgument_getMTensor(Args[0]);
    mint elem = MArgument_getInteger(Args[1]);
    in_data = libData->MTensor_getIntegerData(in);
    mint len = *libData->MTensor_getDimensions(in);
    bool ret = std::any_of(in_data, in_data + len, [&](int x) { return x == elem; });
    MArgument_setBoolean(Res, ret);
    return 0;
}
";

lib=CreateLibrary[src,"lib"];
isMember=LibraryFunctionLoad[lib,"is_member",{{Integer,1,"Shared"},Integer},True|False];
isMember[Range[3],#]&/@{2,4}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are much better off using Not[FreeQ[expr, form]] in place of MemberQ in almost all cases.  MemberQ has a number of different problems, including the tests it uses for equality and the depth of its search into expr, and I don't remember the specifics of them, that you are justified in ignoring it completely.  This is  not to disparage the other answers offered to your question, which look interesting.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with some functions and performance is that they unpack [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/what-is-a-mathematica-packed-array). When the packed array is large, the unpacked array is larger and may exhaust the memory resources available. Functions such as `MemberQ`, `FreeQ`, `FirstPosition`, etc. unpack, but `AnyTrue` does not unpack.  This is the principal difference in speed on an integer array.

Packed example:

```
ll = Range[10^7];

MemberQ[ll, 1] // RepeatedTiming
AnyTrue[ll, # == 1 &] // RepeatedTiming
! FreeQ[ll, 1] // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.462118, True}
{6.21252*10^-7, True}
{0.421446, True}
*)

MemberQ[ll, 10^7] // RepeatedTiming
AnyTrue[ll, # == 10^7 &] // RepeatedTiming
! FreeQ[ll, 10^7] // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.680443, True}
{6.57062, True}  <-- AnyTrue pretty bad here!
{0.660157, True}
*)
```

Unpacked example:

```
lup = Developer`FromPackedArray@ll; // AbsoluteTiming
(*  {0.424071, Null}  *)

MemberQ[lup, 1] // RepeatedTiming
AnyTrue[lup, # == 1 &] // RepeatedTiming
! FreeQ[lup, 1] // RepeatedTiming
(*
{4.34429*10^-7, True}  <-- All methods roughly equivalent
{5.30303*10^-7, True}  <--
{5.77685*10^-7, True}  <--
*)

MemberQ[lup, 10^7] // RepeatedTiming
AnyTrue[lup, # == 10^7 &] // RepeatedTiming
! FreeQ[lup, 10^7] // RepeatedTiming
(*
{0.223027, True}
{5.92986, True}  <-- AnyTrue is still pretty bad here!
{0.231383, True}
*)
```

The timing for unpacking is roughly equal to the timing of `MemberQ` on the packed example.